Superset missing Password and Confirm Password missing while adding User after LDAP integration
I have enabled LDAP for Superset and now I don't see Password and Confirm Password while adding User.
If I remove LDAP, everything works fine.
Superset Version: 4.0.2
Thank you in advance.
Here are my configs
SECRET_KEY = '######################################'
import os
from superset.security import SupersetSecurityManager
from custom_security_manager import CustomSecurityManager
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import (
    AUTH_DB,
    AUTH_LDAP
)


#AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_LDAP
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_LDAP
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER = "ldaps://###############:636"
AUTH_LDAP_USE_TLS = False
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True  
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Admin"  
AUTH_LDAP_FIRSTNAME_FIELD = "givenName"
AUTH_LDAP_LASTNAME_FIELD = "sn"
AUTH_LDAP_EMAIL_FIELD = "uid"  

# Search configs
AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH = "########"
AUTH_LDAP_UID_FIELD = "uid"  
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_USER = "######"                               
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = '#########'  

AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH_FILTER = "##################"

# Mapping from LDAP DN to a list of FAB roles
AUTH_ROLES_MAPPING = {
    "cn=Admin,ou=groups,dc=#####,dc=#####,dc=com": ["Admin"],
}
# The LDAP user attribute which has their role DNs, default is "memberOf"
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_FIELD = "memberOf"
AUTH_ROLES_SYNC_AT_LOGIN = True

CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = CustomSecurityManager

PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME = 1800
AUTH_API_LOGIN_ALLOW_MULTIPLE_PROVIDERS = True

ROW_LIMIT = 5000

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:////app/superset/superset.db?check_same_thread=false'

TALISMAN_ENABLED = False
WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False

# Set this API key to enable Mapbox visualizations
MAPBOX_API_KEY = ''



